# Python creates %USERPROFILE% folder

Tags: python, windows-10, pipx

I am following [this link](https://sourcery.ai/blog/python-best-practices/) to create a cookie-cutter projet on Windows 10.

During the process at this step;

> python3 -m pipx ensurepath

I used python instead of python3, but I am using python 3.7.

The folder %USERPROFILE% gets created, with that name. (Not the windows shortcut).

How to explain this folder creation? How to prevent it from being created?

Comment: pipx does not contain that string anywhere.  Try typing "set H" in a command shell.  Is it possible you have an environment variable called HOME that is set to %USERPROFILE%?  That is a mistake, and that would confuse the Python `pathlib` module.

Comment: this is the answer. thanks @TimRoberts